# Delete table row using PK and row in other table where it's a foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I have a method that deletes a user from my Users table by userId:

```
public void DeleteUser(int id)
    {
        User delObj = (Users.Where(u => u.UserId == id)).Single();
        Users.Remove(delObj);
        SaveChanges();
    }
```

The primary key userId is also used as a foreign key in a userroles table where there is a UserRoleId (PK), UserId (FK), and RoleId (FK). I am unsure how to knock out both rows in both tables with one method.

Thanks in advance!

Here are the exact properties:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}



public class UserRole
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public short RoleId { get; set; }

        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: use a cascading delete on the FK definition?

Comment: Let me know what kind of ORM you are using and I will let you know the exact solution.

Comment: Just edited, let me know if that's enough

Answer (score 1):

Implement the relation between your entities in c#. For example make the collection of Roles entities on User object. The ORM (I guess you are using EntityFramework or NHibernate) will take care of removing dependant objects automatically.

```
class User {
     public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

It should be mapped as many to many relation.

And on your DBContext you must add:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.UserRoles)
            .WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: I updated to show what I have currently. Doesn't seem to be making the connection when I delete a user though.

Comment: Is it EntityFramework? Please check when you make a Get on the "User" if the Roles collection is getting populated?

Comment: Still getting error: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_UserRoles_Users". The conflict occurred in database "C:\CODE\REWORK\REWORK\APP_DATA\AUTHORIZATIONDB.MDF", table "dbo.UserRoles", column 'UserId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Ok just updated my answer please add the mentioned OnModelCreating method on your DBContext that will inform EF to cascade the dependant collection items on delete of User object

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. I added the OnModelCreating method and I am still getting the same error once it tried to SaveChanges()